# How to add a changelog to an RPM created with CPack

Tags: cmake, changelog, cpack

In a typical spec file there is a changelog section. I now use CPack and was wondering how to add such a section. I can't find information about that on the web.

Could I use an external file and indicate it to CPack for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pack a RPM file use CPACK_RPM_CHANGELOG_FILE

May be used to embed a changelog in the spec file. The refered file will be read and directly put after the %changelog section.